# Xquartz infinite crash and restart loop (Mac OS Mojave)

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, xquartz

I have a problem that seems to have occurred to others but I don't see any of the solutions I found over the Internet working for me. I have been trying to fix this all day in different ways.

I'm on Mac OS Mojave.

I don't have the third party softwares some people advise to remove, I don't have any .xinitrc file and apparently never had, and I have reinstalled in several ways already. Xquartz used to work perfectly fine about 3 weeks ago, now that I have to use it again with x2go it just enters this boot loop that can't even be killed.

I have tried reinstalling 2.7.11 (the one I always had and that worked before today) several times, and I tried retrograding to 2.7.9 as well but that gave me another error.

The most recent error with 2.7.9 is

`An error occurred while starting the X11 server: "Could not create lock file in /tmp/.tX0-lock"`

As for the error I keep having in 2.7.11 ("Xquartz quit unexpectedly")...
It's too big so I'll leave the entire file here: https://pastebin.com/0wv11ELD
I'll also paste part of it below

```
Path:                  /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11.bin
Identifier:            org.macosforge.xquartz.X11
Version:               2.7.11 (2.7.112)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           X11.bin [555]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2020-05-20 00:22:20.245 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G1012)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     4.1 (17P1081)
Anonymous UUID:        39319B7E-57A8-F9EA-CBA1-4145480B04F7


Time Awake Since Boot: 160 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        4

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
X.Org X Server 1.18.4 Build Date: 20161025
Could not create lock file in /tmp/.tX0-lock

abort() called

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5d68522a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5d68576c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff315c999e __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 328
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff315c8f0c __CFRunLoopRun + 1612
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff315c866e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 455
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff308271ab RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff30826ee5 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 603
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff30826c76 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2ebbf77d _DPSNextEvent + 1135
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2ebbe46b -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1361
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2ebb8588 -[NSApplication run] + 699
11  X11.bin                         0x00000001000087ca X11ApplicationMain + 1520
12  X11.bin                         0x000000010001101e server_main + 185
13  X11.bin                         0x0000000100001b0b do_start_x11_server + 445
14  X11.bin                         0x00000001000028a2 _Xstart_x11_server + 125
15  X11.bin                         0x0000000100002a06 mach_startup_server + 80
16  libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5d69c782 mach_msg_server + 430
17  X11.bin                         0x00000001000020fd main + 1476
18  X11.bin                         0x0000000100001518 start + 52

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5d7433f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.asl-redirect
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff5d73e5d6 DYLD-STUB$$_platform_memmove + 0
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5d522b04 voucher_activity_trace_v + 20
2   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff5d761481 _os_log_impl_flatten_and_send + 7133
3   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff5d762c3b _os_log_with_args_impl + 491
4   libsystem_asl.dylib             0x00007fff5d58273f asl_log + 255
5   libsystem_asl.dylib             0x00007fff5d58d2d0 _read_redirect + 214
6   libsystem_asl.dylib             0x00007fff5d58d0c0 read_from_source + 23
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5d50363d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5d505de6 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 414
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5d514f42 _dispatch_source_invoke + 2056
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5d509792 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 268
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5d50a396 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 385
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5d5126ed _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5d743611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5d7433fd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:: Dispatch queue: org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.NSEventsToX11EventsQueue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5d68886a __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5d74756e _pthread_cond_wait + 722
2   X11.bin                         0x0000000100008863 -[X11Application(Private) sendX11NSEvent:] + 56
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5d5025f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5d50363d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5d5098e0 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 602
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5d50a396 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 385
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5d5126ed _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5d743611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5d7433fd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5d68b2c6 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5d746bf1 pthread_kill + 284
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff5d5f56a6 abort + 127
3   X11.bin                         0x000000010012e8a3 OsAbort + 9
4   X11.bin                         0x000000010000dfc3 AbortDDX + 23
5   X11.bin                         0x0000000100134b36 AbortServer + 34
6   X11.bin                         0x00000001001334fc FatalError + 315
7   X11.bin                         0x000000010012cb4f LockServer + 394
8   X11.bin                         0x000000010012c854 OsInit + 426
9   X11.bin                         0x00000001000dc026 dix_main + 274
10  X11.bin                         0x0000000100010f5e server_thread + 38
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5d7442eb _pthread_body + 126
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5d747249 _pthread_start + 66
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5d74340d thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5d68c61a __select + 10
1   libxcb.1.dylib                  0x00000001003d965a _xcb_in_read_block + 398
2   libxcb.1.dylib                  0x00000001003d6ca7 xcb_connect_to_fd + 492
3   libxcb.1.dylib                  0x00000001003da324 xcb_connect_to_display_with_auth_info + 847
4   libX11.6.dylib                  0x00000001002c25d5 _XConnectXCB + 200
5   libX11.6.dylib                  0x00000001002b40ad XOpenDisplay + 187
6   X11.bin                         0x0000000100023999 xpbproxy_run + 119
7   X11.bin                         0x0000000100008819 xpbproxy_x_thread + 9
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5d7442eb _pthread_body + 126
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5d747249 _pthread_start + 66
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5d74340d thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5d68522a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5d68576c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff315c999e __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 328
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff315c8f0c __CFRunLoopRun + 1612
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff315c866e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 455
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2ebc74a2 _NSEventThread + 175
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5d7442eb _pthread_body + 126
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5d747249 _pthread_start + 66
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5d74340d thread_start + 13

Thread 4 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x000070001024f000  rcx: 0x000070001024e7d8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x000000000000a033  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x000070001024e810  rsp: 0x000070001024e7d8
   r8: 0x0a58444474726f62   r9: 0x000070001024e830  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x000000000000a033  r13: 0x0000000100167e20  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x000000000000002d
  rip: 0x00007fff5d68b2c6  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff93dc5188

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133
```

The one suspect I might still have is some permission problem maybe caused by recent some recent chmod, maybe? I'm really all kinds of lost here and I can't advance in my work...